# SAS VBA connection

Tags: vba, excel, sas

I tried to run a SAS code through VBA. I'm running SAS on a server. I have a test SAS program "**Program1.sas**" which I've kept on the server. Below is the VBA code that I've used. The SAS code is running but the output dataset is just showing the column headers and the rows are empty.Can anyone help me what could be the possible reason.

```
Sub Form_Load23()
 Dim obObjectFactory As New SASObjectManager.ObjectFactory

 Dim obObjectKeeper As New SASObjectManager.ObjectKeeper

 Dim obServer As New SASObjectManager.ServerDef

 Dim obSAS As SAS.Workspace

 Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection

 Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

 obServer.MachineDNSName = "xyz"     

 obServer.Protocol = SASObjectManager.Protocols.ProtocolBridge

 obServer.Port = 8871



 obObjectFactory.LogEnabled = True

 Set obSAS = obObjectFactory.CreateObjectByServer("sas", True, obServer,"userid", "password")


obSAS.LanguageService.Submit ("options source2; %include '/abc/AFP/shikhar.gupta1/amg/**Program1.sas**';")

End Sub'
```

Comment: Is your server a Stored Process Server, a Workspace Server or something else?

Comment: Do you have output if you run the program from for instance Enterprise Guide? Did you see the log somewhere while debugging?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think it is a workspace server but I'm not sure. We create and access libraries by connecting to Filezilla  where we all have some space alloted. I've run the code from instance Enterprise Guide and it was giving a right output with data. No while running the VBA code no log came up.

Comment: use `obSAS.LanguageService.FlushLog` to get the log and post it here.  Your code looks OK first pass, so it is possible that the ERROR is on the SAS side.  Your log will help figure that out.

Comment: you can also use PROC PRINTTO to save the log comewhere on the server and then get it with filezilla.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to change the security settings in excel. Find the security settings and protected viewing. The remove all the check marks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue on the SAS side.  It can happen when your user does not have the metadata 'read' permission on the relevant dataset.  It can also happen if your program has an error, and `options obs=0;` is set.

As @vasilij mentions, use `proc printto` to write your log to a file system and check for issues, also use SMC to check your metadata permissions.